# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted top Tab bar component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, redux

[image: navigation problem image]

I cleared tabs, removed states, implemented empty components but still the same issues. it happens Only when I navigate to back menu

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
```

[Github link You can see code](https://github.com/ulvibashir/Client-App)

Comment: can you add some snippets so as to get more context

Comment: we don't need to see the whole stack trace. please just show the component it's complaining about

Comment: I cant copy whole component here so, I can put here github link https://github.com/ulvibashir/Client-App

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform state update of unmounted component. Instead you should whatever you want to do with state before you leave component. Consider using `useEffect` return function or react-navigations `focus`

Comment: I dont have anything to do on useffect unmount function